# How to find the return type of a method in Groovy

Tags: groovy, reflection

I am trying to convert a Map `<String, String>` to an Object. 
Currently getting the groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.
Here is the code:

```
mapToClass(Map map, Object input) {
    map.each { key, value ->
        input."set${key}" value
    }
}
```

I need to identify the type of `input."get${key}"` and cast `value` to the same type before assigning it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is something I found that's working

`input.getClass().getMethod("get${key}").getReturnType()`